# React Spring - Animate list - one item in list at a time

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Given a list:

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000000;
}

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Using react-spring, I am trying to animate the colour of each item in a list (one by one) every 3 seconds and loop from start to finish.

For example:

1. From - Color starts as black
2. Enter - Color changes to red
3. Leave - Color changes back to black

I can get an individual item to show and colour to update and then hides (as only 1 item from the list is being animated), but not the whole list to show and change the colour of each item 1 by 1.

```
const ColourListTransition = (items, delay) => {
  const [index, setIndex ] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((state) => ( state + 1 ) % items.length);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return useTransition(items[index], {
    from: { color: '#000000' },
    enter: { color: "#FF0000" },
    leave: { color: "#000000" },
    loop: true,
    config: config.molasses
  })
}

{ ColourListTransition(['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3', 'item 4'], 3000)(({ color }, item) => (
  <animated.li
    key={ item }
    style={ { color, display: 'inline-block', listStyleType: 'none' } }
  >
    { item }
  </animated.li>
)) }
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing at the moment?

Comment: @DanielDuong because we are passing an array of items, they all animate at once. Need to work out how I can apply animation to on item at a time.

Comment: can you attach a video example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with `useTransition` but I just could not figure it out.  It was easy when I switched to using [`useSprings`](https://react-spring.io/hooks/use-springs) instead.  So this might not be the most elegant solution but it works.

We create an array of spring animations which correspond to the items in your list.  The color of each item is based on whether its index matches the active index from state.  `enter` and `leave` don't really come into play here since you always have same 4 items in your array.  I kept your `useState` and `useEffect` hooks the same.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { animated, config, useSprings } from "@react-spring/web";

const ColourListTransition = ({delay, items, activeColor, inactiveColor}) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setIndex((state) => (state + 1) % items.length);
    }, delay);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  const [springs] = useSprings(
    // count
    items.length,
    // properties as a function of index
    (i) => ({
      // determine the current color based on the index
      color: i === index ? activeColor : inactiveColor,
      // all items start out black
      from: { color: inactiveColor },
      config: config.molasses
    }),
    // dependency on index state
    [index]
  );

  return (
    <ul>
      {springs.map(({ color }, i) => (
        <animated.li
          key={items[i]}
          style={{ color, display: "inline-block", listStyleType: "none" }}
        >
          {items[i]}
        </animated.li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ColourListTransition
      items={["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]}
      delay={3000}
      activeColor={"#FF0000"}
      inactiveColor={"#000000"}
    />
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-field-202yq?file=/src/App.tsx:656-666)

Comment: Perfect, useSprings was the way to go

Comment: `useTransition` is to defer rendering when updating state data. It is not a visual transition utility.